# How to calculate numbers from a file that has numbers and text using awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Here's the file:

```
Name Gender Mid1(25%) Mid2(25%) EndSem(50%)
AA    M       20         15         35
BB    F       22         17         44
CC    F       19         14         25
DD    M       15         20         42
EE    F       18         22         30      
FF    M        0         20         45
```

The assignment I have explained that I have to add up the total of Mid1, Mid2, EndSem and display it beside each corresponding name. It also entails that awk must be used to read the file.

Like this:

```
AA 70
BB 83
CC 58
...
```

I've read many examples on how to add the sum from a file, but I'm having troubles understanding how to implement them for what I need. Any help would be great appreciated!

Comment: Good that you have told us that you have read many examples about question, request you to please add some of your tries too in your question as we do encourage people to add their efforts in their questions.

Comment: It looks like you need to sum the fields from `$3` to `$NF` and print `$1` and the sum.  And you need to skip record number 1 because it is header information.  Which part of that causes trouble to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR>1{print $1,$3+$4+$5}' Input_file
```

OR if fields are always last 3 fields  which you need the sum(irrespective of their column numbers, means they can any other than 3,4 or 5) then try following.

```
awk 'FNR>1{print $1,$(NF-2)+$(NF-1)+$NF}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't come across FNR or $NF when trying to find a solution. Does FNR>1 tell awk to a skip the first line? I really had no idea the command would be that simple, all other examples I read seemed overly complicated!

Comment: @Austin, Your welcome, but it doesn't matter about right or wrong you can still add your efforts whatever you tried to solve your own problem and this is applicable to all community members, I will still request you to like you said `"you have seen examples"` you can add your tries simple, no one will say why its wrong or etc, important thing is efforts, cheers and happy learning.